# Issues deploying django [django, git, heroku]

Tags: django, heroku

I created a heroku app:

```
$ heroku create olp-website
Creating olp-website... done, stack is cedar
```

Then I tried to push my git branch to the app:

```
git push heroku deploy
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 8.48 KiB, done.
Total 25 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build.
To git@heroku.com:olp-website.git
 * [new branch]      deploy -> deploy
```

Then,I tried to add addons to the app:

```
$ heroku addons:add cloudamqp:panda
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.
```

So this is both a general and a specific question. Does the branch have to be the master branch (see "Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build")? And is it possible to be inside a specific heroku app or do you have to specify the app for each addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - check out Heroku's Dev Center.  [The article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code) tells you how to do it:
`git push heroku yourbranch:master`

As for the add-on, just specify the app.  So something like

`heroku addons:add cloudamqp:panda -a myappname`

Comment: Thanks very much for that info - exactly what I wanted.